# Select destination Continue button disabled

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am creating application installation through apple packagemaker, 
for me, always initially continue button on select destination screen is disable, is there any way to fix this problem .. 
I tried all possible option like Easy Install, Custom Install , Easy & Custom Install etc....

Answer (score 0):

You probably have more than 1 disk installed - and the top-half of the screen displays all of them.

You need to actively select one of the drives; even though it looks like one is already highlighted.

Once you click on one of them, the "continue" button will activate.